# Import Error: cannot import name 'BaseEstimator'

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda

I am getting the following error when I m trying to import from `sklearn.cluster`:

[image]

The same thing has been working for a few days but suddenly it stopped working and I tried to update the `sklearn` in terminal but it doesn't help. Can someone figure out where the error is from?

Comment: Please paste your error instead of link to screenshot. Also it would be good if you paste some code that produces this error here.Anyway I think this is some issue with version incompatibility between packages you are using. Perhaps _downgrading_ sklearn might help.

Comment: I'm just throwing this out: It looks like sklearn is trying to import Python's `copy` module and you have a file called `copy.py` in your working dir (i.e. your desktop). I don't know if that's got anything to do with it but you should probably change that filename.

Comment: Thx! The error is caused by copy.py, after I removed it, everything s good now.

Answer (score 1):

I faced same problem
So try
**from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator**